# How to make selectedItem in a SelectList be dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a SelectList:

```
SelectList DropDownListOfCatergories = new SelectList(UnitOfWork.ClassifiedCategories.FindAll().OrderBy(Order()), "Category", "Category");
```

This works fine as you can see I am ordering the list. Now when someone wants to edit something the selectedItem is alway's defaults to the first one no matter what category it is in.

How do I code it so the selectedItem is the correct category the classified is in?
i.e dynamically generated from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it in a helper method:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetClassifiedCategories(IEnumerable<ClassifiedCategory> categories, string selectedCategoryName)
{
    var list=new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var cat in categories)
    {
        var item = new SelectListItem()
                       {
                           Text = cat.Name,
                           Value = cat.Id
                        };
        if (cat.Name==selectedCategoryName)
            item.Selected = true;
        list.Add(cat);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Obviously you would want to do a compare against ids rather than names. Also making a call directly to unitofwork is not desirible (from application architecture point of view)

Here is the an example of how you would use this in a view (Razor syntax):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ClassifiedCategoryId, Helpers.GetClassifedCategories(UnitOfWork.ClassifiedCategories.FindAll().OrderBy(Order()), Model.ClassifiedCategoryId))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow. Do you mean you want to specify the selected item? If so (and I'm using MVC 1.0 here), use the overload that takes 4 parameters, e.g.

```
SelectList DropDownListOfCatergories = new SelectList(UnitOfWork.ClassifiedCategories.FindAll().OrderBy(Order()), "Category", "Category", "My Selected Item");
```